# .NET Dictionaries have same keys and values, but aren't "equal"

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, equality

This test fails:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;        

[TestMethod()]
        public void dictEqualTest() {
            IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            IDictionary<string, int> dictClone = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            dict[x.ToString()] = x;
            dictClone[x.ToString()] = x;
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(dict, dictClone); // fails here
        Assert.IsTrue(dict.Equals(dictClone)); // and here, if the first is commented out
        Assert.AreSame(dict, dictClone); // also fails
    }
```

Am I misunderstanding something about how a `Dictionary` works?

I'm looking for the Java equivalent of `.equals()`, not trying to check referential equality.

Comment: I would start with a Stack Trace - which method does AreEqual call? By the way, is this MBUnit, NUnit, MS Test / other?

Comment: This is the built in Visual Studio 2008 Pro unit testing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dictionary class does not override `Object.Equals` method as seen from MSDN doco:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

> Determines whether the specified
>   Object is equal to the current Object.

Seeing that you are doing unit testing, your <strike>`Assert` class should provide a test method for testing if two collections are the same.</strike>

Microsoft Unit testing framework provides `CollectionAssert` class for the purpose of comparing collections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert_members%28VS.80%29.aspx

**EDIT** Dictionary implements `ICollection` interface, can you see if that just works? You might need to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243753%28VS.80%29.aspx) to compare two dictionary entries.

**EDIT** Hmm IDictionary does not implement `ICollection`, which is a bit of a pain. This however works (albeit a hack):

```
IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
IDictionary<string, int> dictClone = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    dict[x.ToString()] = x;
    dictClone[x.ToString()] = x;
}

CollectionAssert.AreEqual((System.Collections.ICollection)dict, (System.Collections.ICollection)dictClone);
```

THe above approach will work for instances of `Dictionary`, however if you are testing a method that returns `IDictionary` it might fail if the implmentation changes. My advice is to change the code to use `Dictionary` instead of `IDictionary` (since `IDictionary` is not readonly, so you are not hiding all that much by using that instead of concreate `Dictionary`).

Comment: Looks good. But how do I convert from a `Dictionary` to `ICollection`? A `ICollection` only has one type argument.

Comment: I've been looking at that documentation but I can't find anything that I could use to compare dictionaries.

Comment: That is intriguing, but what `ICompare` would I use? Do I have to write my own?

The cast to `ICollection` doesn't work. What type would I use as the argument? The key or the value?

Comment: Your above hack wouldn't compile for me. The error:

Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>' requires '1' type arguments

Comment: Try `System.Collections.ICollection`.

Comment: `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` would work only if both dictionaries enumerators enumerate the elements from the dictionaries in the same order, and I wouldn't expect that to be guaranteed

Answer (score 15):

If you are specifically interested in how you can fix this from unit testing perspective:

**Try this**

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(dict.ToList(), dictClone.ToList());
```

**Explanation**

There are [extension methods on IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) - such as `.ToList()` - available in .Net 3.5 and up, which will convert the dictionary into a collection of KeyValuePair that can be easily compared with `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`.

They'll even give reasonably helpful error messages! Example usage:

```
IDictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}, {"c", "3"}};

IDictionary<string, string> d2 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"b", "2"}, { "a", "1"}, {"c", "3"}}; // same key-values, different order

IDictionary<string, string> d3 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "a", "1"}, {"d", "2"}, {"c", "3"}}; // key of the second element differs from d1

IDictionary<string, string> d4 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "a", "1"}, {"b", "4"}, {"c", "3"}}; // value of the second element differs from d1

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(d1.ToList(), d2.ToList());
//CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(d1.ToList(), d3.ToList()); // fails!
//CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(d1.ToList(), d4.ToList()); // fails!

// if uncommented, the 2 tests above fail with error:
//   CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1
//   occurrence(s) of <[b, 2]>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s).
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? As far as I know CollectionAssert is an extension method in unit testing framework like NUnit and MSTest - not in .Net.

Comment: The context of the question was unit testing, although I grant you that it was not explicitly limited to that scope. Given that, I think the answer is useful to both the OP and others who come across this looking for a  solution for testing. I'm surprised someone found my answer so incorrect/unhelpful/wrong-headed as to actually give it a down vote.

Comment: Same [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219047/net-dictionaries-have-same-keys-and-values-but-arent-equal#comment134787589_2219057) as for the accepted answer: I don't think you can rely on dictionaries element to be enumerated in any specific order.

Comment: @yannick1976, `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent ` does not care about the order.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
Assert.AreEqual(dict, dictClone)
```

You are comparing object references, which aren't equal.

Comment: +1, additionally I'm not sure if MS's test suite has collection compare tools, but I'm pretty sure NUnit does.

Comment: It might be because it isn't obvious you're highlighting the failing line. (*2 years ago when you answered, I thought it obvious.*)

Comment: @sixlettervariables - It seemed obvious to me 2 years ago, and it still does today. I mean, I have the highlighted line right above the explanation, not sure what else I could have done.

Comment: It confounded me too - it looks like it might be a proposed solution - I've edited the original answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I have used an extension method that checks two sequences for equal items

```
public static bool CheckForEquality<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> destination)
{
    if (source.Count() != destination.Count())
    {
        return false;
    }

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            dictionary[value] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary[value]++;
        }
    }

    foreach (var member in destination)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(member))
        {
            return false;
        }

        dictionary[member]--;
    }

    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        if (kvp.Value != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you this lesson in Linq ! Being able to study this type of code is very valuable to a "mere mortal" like me :)

Comment: @BillW, There is nothing about LINQ here. 
This is a feature called extension method which of course was developed mainly for LINQ.

Comment: Nice! One thing to note though; you should check for NULL-values before you do 'source.Count()' and 'destination.Count()'.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely not understanding how reference types work.

`Dictionary` does not override `object.Equals()`. Thus, it uses reference equality - basically, if both references are pointing to the same instance, they're equal, otherwise they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The NUnit class `CollectionAssert` has an [`AreEquivalent` method which accepts `IEnumerable` as parameters](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/CollectionAssert.cs#L200), so in that case it's as simple as

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(dict, dictClone);
```

because `Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: MSTest also includes `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` and it works for dictionaries in the same way. Please include that in this post.