# How to compare two generic lists in C# 3.0?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, list-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

What is the best way to compare to generic two generic lists in C# 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare regardless of element order, try the **UnorderedEqual<T>** method from here:

- [C# List Element Equality](http://dotnetperls.com/list-equals)

Otherwise:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var areSame = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2);
```

Comment: cxfx: The poster indicated that they are using C# 3.0 which implies .NET 3.5 which has most of the tools needed to compare IEnumerable<T> implementations as sets, or as ordered sequences, the list equality link doesn't add much to the solution.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I need to implement IEqualityCompairer interface to do my own comparison actually. The list are:

ListA<myObject> , ListB<myObject> ; "myObject" is fairly complex object that I need to compare few property. Thats why I need a custom comparer. In addition those lists are values of two dictionary. So my data model is like this:

Dictionary<myObjectA, List<myObjectA>> to be compaired against Dictionary<myObjectB,List<myObjectB>>. Keys are OK but I got problem with Values of those two dictionary

Thanks for your reply
Morz

Comment: Yes, element order is not a matter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two *sequences* in .NET 3.5 and beyond (that's the version of the framework which C# 3.0 ships with), then you should use the [SeqenceEqual extension method on the Enumerable class in the System.Linq namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx).

However, for this, it will use the default equality comparer for the type parameter T in the `IEnumerable<T>` implementations it is comparing.

If you want to change the way that equality is checked for, then you should pass an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the SequenceEqual method to use when comparing the items from each sequence.

Also, if you are trying to see if two *sets* are equal (as represented by `IEnumerable<T>`) then your best bet is to check use the [Except extension method on the Enumerable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) and make sure that the result set doesn't have any entries, and that both `IEnumerable<T>` implementations have the same number of entries (since Except can return an empty sequence even with different length sequences passed to it) which you can do with the [Count extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219047/net-dictionaries-have-same-keys-and-values-but-arent-equal/2219125#2219125), it provides a method that determines whether two sequences contain the same elements.